# How to SWIG my entire c++ code base to Java

Tags: java, swig

I have used swig to do generate java bindings for independent classes. However when I tried to do it for my existing codebase which is quite complex, having calls for STL , OSG and OpenGL. When I am trying to swig it am getting issues.
Here is my .i file

```
/* File : Line.i */
%module Line

%{
#include "Elements/LineFeatureObject.h"
%}

/* Let's just grab the original header file here */
%include "Elements/LineFeatureObject.h
```

This headers includes several other headers files. Some of them are read by the code while for some it gives the following warnings.
Warning 401: Nothing known about base class 'ELEMENTS::ILineAlgebra'. Ignored.
These classes are listed in the same location with rest of the classes. So am not sure what is going wrong with just couple of these classes.

Moving on I am able to get _wrap.cxx but when am compiling it am getting the following errors.
error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
error C2144: syntax error : 'void' should be preceded by ';'
error C2086: 'int WINGDIAPI' : redefinition
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\GL/gl.h(1152) : see declaration of 'WINGDIAPI'
.
.
.

Have not listed all of them here.
Can you help me find way around these errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SWIG by default only processes the top-level file named by `%include`.  It does not recurse into additional `#include` files.  You must explicitly `%include` the headers files you wish SWIG to process.

SWIG also does not know anything about STL, but there are some SWIG headers that can add support for STL types like `std::string` and `std::vector`.  STL templates must be explicitly instantiated and given a target language name:  Example:

```
%include <std_string.i>
%include <std_vector.i>
%template(IntVector) std::vector<int>;
```

SWIG also does not know about Windows types and compiler extensions and can be confused by `__stdcall`, `__cdecl`, `__declspec(dllexport)`, `DWORD`, `UINT`, etc., but this include helps:

```
%include <windows.i>
```